# Determine whether a link is text or an image

Tags: jquery

I need to write an if statement based on whether or not an href contains a text link or an image link.  So if I get the content of the link like this :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     $('a').click(function(event) {
     var $linkContent = $(this).html();
     // this doesnt work.. just one of the things I tried
     // var imgsrc = $(this).attr('src');
        });

    })
```

I also thought I could go the other way and just get the text content like :

```
var linkContent = $(this).text();
```

Then when I alert this variable it shows text for text links and is blank for images.  Great!  But still isnt working for me.  I was going to write rules based on its .length but if I alert the lengths the image links are still giving me an integer even though if alert the .text() it is blank.  I am confused!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` in your click handler will always be an anchor element because it's attached to the anchor elements in your code. however just do

```
 $('a').click(function(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.find("img").length) { //searches within the anchor element for an img element
       //it's an image
    } else {
       //no images in the anchor tag
    }
})
```

Comment: Ack! So easy, (this) is always tripping me up.  Thank you, thank you!

Answer (score -4):

You should use HTTP HEAD to see the content context.

Here is a sample which you can snip bits from , it was used as a checker to see if a url exists or not :

```
public static boolean exists(String URLName){
try {
  HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
  // note : you may also need
  //        HttpURLConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false)
  HttpURLConnection con =
     (HttpURLConnection) new URL(URLName).openConnection();
  con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
  return (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
}
catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   return false;
}
```

}

Comment: The question was about jQuery. This most certainly is not Javascript, and therefore not jQuery.